# jq - backslash n to column output

Tags: html, json, jq

The CloudWatch log format for Aurora MySQL delayed queries is as follows.

```
    "events": [
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1669369490368, 
            "timestamp": 1669369486225, 
            "message": "# Time: 2022-11-25T09:44:46.225359Z\n# User@Host: Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]  Id:   346\n# Query_time: 1.000765  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0\nuse mysql;\nSET timestamp=1669369486;\nselect sleep(1);"
        }, 
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1669369525539, 
            "timestamp": 1669369520857, 
            "message": "# Time: 2022-11-25T09:45:20.857181Z\n# User@Host: Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]  Id:   346\n# Query_time: 1.000153  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0\nuse testDB;\nSET timestamp=1669369520;\nselect sleep(1);"
        }
    ],
```

I want to create html format using jq command.
I want to parse message field and The desired format is:

| Time | User@Host | ID | Query_time | Lock_time | Rows_sent | Rows_examined | Query |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-25T09:44:46.225359 | Test[Test] @ [111.111.111.111] | 346 | 1.000765 | 0.000000 | 1 | 0 | use mysql;\nSET timestamp=1669369486;\nselect sleep(1); |
| 2022-11-25T09:45:20.857181 | Test[Test] @ [111.111.111.111] | 346 | 1.000153 | 0.000000 | 1 | 0 | use testDB;\nSET timestamp=1669369486;\nselect sleep(1); |

I tried to do it, but my knowledge is lacking, so I'm asking for help.
Is it possible to divide it like above or even a column?

Comment: "I tried to do it" -- show us what you tried and we can help correct any mistakes

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I couldn't attach it because the code was too messy and long because I tried to mix jq and shell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting the correct values is cumbersome, but possible. Given a *valid* input JSON:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1669369490368, 
            "timestamp": 1669369486225, 
            "message": "# Time: 2022-11-25T09:44:46.225359Z\n# User@Host: Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]  Id:   346\n# Query_time: 1.000765  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0\nuse mysql;\nSET timestamp=1669369486;\nselect sleep(1);"
        }, 
        {
            "ingestionTime": 1669369525539, 
            "timestamp": 1669369520857, 
            "message": "# Time: 2022-11-25T09:45:20.857181Z\n# User@Host: Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]  Id:   346\n# Query_time: 1.000153  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0\nuse testDB;\nSET timestamp=1669369520;\nselect sleep(1);"
        }
    ]
}
```

First, transform the input data into an array of arrays of the form …

```
[
  [ "cell 1.1", "cell 1.2", "cell 1.3" ],
  [ "cell 2.1", "cell 2.2", "cell 2.3" ],
  [ "cell 3.1", "cell 3.2", "cell 3.3" ]
]
```

This can be done with the following jq program:

```
[
    ["Time","User@Host","ID","Query time","Lock time","Rows sent","Rows examined","Query"],
    (
        .events[] | .message/"\n" | map(
            (select(startswith("# Time: ")) | ltrimstr("# Time: ")),
            (select(startswith("# User@Host: ")) | ltrimstr("# User@Host: ")/":" | (
                 (first | rtrimstr("  Id")),
                 (.[-1] | tonumber | tostring)
            )),
            (select(startswith("# Query_time"))|[splits(" +";"")][2,4,6,8])
        )
        + [.[3:] | join("\n")]
    )
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  [
    "Time",
    "User@Host",
    "ID",
    "Query time",
    "Lock time",
    "Rows sent",
    "Rows examined",
    "Query"
  ],
  [
    "2022-11-25T09:44:46.225359Z",
    "Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]",
    "346",
    "1.000765",
    "0.000000",
    "1",
    "0",
    "use mysql;\nSET timestamp=1669369486;\nselect sleep(1);"
  ],
  [
    "2022-11-25T09:45:20.857181Z",
    "Test[Test] @  [111.111.111.111]",
    "346",
    "1.000153",
    "0.000000",
    "1",
    "0",
    "use testDB;\nSET timestamp=1669369520;\nselect sleep(1);"
  ]
]
```

Once you have a matrix with the correct values, the rest is quite straightforward. Add the html tags (named functions make the code more understandable) and make sure to use the `@html` to escape any HTML entities:

```
def to_table: "<table>", .[] ,"</table>";
def to_row: "<tr>", .[] ,"</tr>";
def to_header: "<th>", . ,"</th>";
def to_cell: "<td>", . ,"</td>";

# previous code ... plus:
| map(map(@html))
| .[0] |= map(to_header)
| .[1:][] |= map(to_cell)
| map(to_row)
| to_table
```

Output:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Time
</th>
<th>
User@Host
</th>
<th>
ID
</th>
<th>
Query time
</th>
<th>
Lock time
</th>
<th>
Rows sent
</th>
<th>
Rows examined
</th>
<th>
Query
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
2022-11-25T09:44:46.225359Z
</td>
<td>
Test[Test] @ [111.111.111.111]
</td>
<td>
346
</td>
<td>
1.000765
</td>
<td>
0.000000
</td>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
0
</td>
<td>
use mysql;
SET timestamp=1669369486;
select sleep(1);
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
2022-11-25T09:45:20.857181Z
</td>
<td>
Test[Test] @ [111.111.111.111]
</td>
<td>
346
</td>
<td>
1.000153
</td>
<td>
0.000000
</td>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
0
</td>
<td>
use testDB;
SET timestamp=1669369520;
select sleep(1);
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, build the table output as you go. This might be slightly faster because it does not need to build and rebuild arrays all the time (but it does not separate the HTML formatting and the table transformation is cleanly as the first solution):

```
def to_row: "<tr>", .[] ,"</tr>";
def to_header: "<th>", . ,"</th>";
def to_cell: "<td>", . ,"</td>";

"<table>",
(["Time","User@Host","ID","Query time","Lock time","Rows sent","Rows examined","Query"]
| map(@html | to_header) | to_row),
(
    .events[] | .message/"\n" | map(
        (select(startswith("# Time: ")) | ltrimstr("# Time: ")),
        (select(startswith("# User@Host: ")) | ltrimstr("# User@Host: ")/":" | (
             (first | rtrimstr("  Id")),
             (.[-1] | tonumber | tostring)
        )),
        (select(startswith("# Query_time"))|[splits(" +";"")][2,4,6,8])
    )
    + [.[3:] | join("\n")]
    | map(@html | to_cell)
    | to_row
),
"</table>"
```

NB The program must be called with `--raw-output`/`-r` to remove the double quotes from all top-level strings. Only then will you get valid HTML.

Comment: To save the hassle with the final to-html step, it might be worth considering using one of the many tsv2html command-line utilities that are freely available.

Comment: @peak valid point. Then `jq` would only be used to `.events[].message` and then use a different tool (awk/sed/perl/python) to produce the CSV/TSV, then run it through a converter. (I didn't see any tabs in the Q, only repeated spaces)

Comment: you are a genius Thank you very much. I was able to achieve the desired result using the script you provided. Thank you for your help, and I will try to be helpful to others as well.

Comment: @knittl      
Can I ask you just one more question?
I want to exclude messages that contain some strings. I want to remove the Test string from message, and I wrote it as below by supporting the contains and not options in the jq command. I'm looking for opinions on whether this is the right direction to go.
```.events[] | .message/"\n" | contains("test") | not | map(```

Comment: Sorry, I tested and it retures True or False.  Im gonna try finding other way.

Comment: ```/usr/local/bin/jq -r '.events[] | select(.message | contains("test") | not)'``` Is worked.  I will try to incorporate it into the script you provided. We'll also check out the ability to filter on two strings.

Comment: @knittl  Finally I found it.  ```.events[] | select(.message | contains("test") or contains("sample") | not ) | .message/"\n" | map(``` Thank you again.

Comment: @P.Lonnie yes, you need `select` to filter based on a predicate. Note that you can avoid the duplication of `.message`: `.events[] | .message | select(contains("test") or contains("sample") | not) / "\n" | map(…`